# 2x2 contingency table with some data-points paired and some independent

Tags: missing-data, assumptions, paired-data, contingency-tables

There are two items in a task (item A, item B). On each of the two items participant can score success (1), failure (0), or not provide a meaningful answer (NA). Participants with NA on both item are excluded.
I want to test the hypothesis that proportion of successes on item A is significantly higher than on item B. Is there a statistical test that I can use while pooling together both observations from participants who provided meaningful (i.e. either 1 or 0) answers on both items (i.e. provided paired observations, on item A and item B) and observations from participants who provided meaningful answer on only one of the two items (i.e. provided independent observations, either on item A or item B)?

At the moment I am thinking I should analyze the data in two separate contingency tables: one for paired observations and one for independent observations. Is there a way to test the hypothesis without splitting the sample this way?

Comment: Is there any meaning when participants do not give a meaningful answer? If there is then maybe you could better model this with a 3x3 table.

Comment: I see. The NAs have no meaning for the tested hypothesis. They are rather artifact of the method.
But also, I miss how it would become a 3x3 table if NAs is included. Not 2x3? Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following contingency table

$$\begin{array}{r|ccc|c}
& \text{Item A: success} & \text{Item A: failure} & \text{Item A: NA} & \text{Total} \\
\hline 
\text{Item B: success} & p_{11} & p_{01} & p_{\cdot 1} & P_{B=1} \\
\text{Item B: failure}& p_{10} & p_{00} & p_{\cdot 0} & P_{B=0} \\
\text{Item B: NA}  & p_{1\cdot} & p_{0\cdot} & p_{\cdot \cdot} & P_{B=NA}\\
\hline
\text{Total} & p_{A=1} & p_{A=0} & p_{A=NA} & 1
\end{array}$$

Then compare $p_{A=1}$ with $p_{B=1}$ and for the hypothesis test or confidence interval you take into account that they are slightly correlated.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining more the 3x3 table! Do I understand correctly that the comparison you are suggesting (pA=1 vs. pB=1) can provide test of the hypothesis (that proportion of successes is higher for item A than for item B), as long as NAs are approximately equally distributed between item A and B? I do not know now if this is the case and I am considering, if I there is a way to test the hypothesis without having to assume flat distribution of NAs accorss items.
Thank you, again for your answer.

Comment: You could also compare $\frac{p_{a=1}}{p_{a=1}+p_{a=0}} \,\,\text{vs}\,\, \frac{p_{b=1}}{p_{b=1}+p_{b=0}}$ but the computations for the distributions will be more difficult. This is why I asked whether the NAs are still meaningfull (are they occuring independently from a and b or is it possible that the sampling or task had an influence?).